# Type mismatch error when comparing cell value with "#N/A"

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following VBA code to look for specific text in Column B of my worksheet and delete the entire row if it is found. However, I keep getting a `Type Mismatch Error` when I run it.  I have tried modifying every value in the indicated line of code (**) because that is what is throwing the error, with no luck. Help?

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1000 To 2 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "#N/A" Then ' line that errors out
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Change conditional statement to

```
 If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
```